# Nest exclude property on search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a search by string from all properties big object:

```
q => q.QueryString(qfqqs => qfqqs.Query(mainSearch).DefaultOperator(Operator.And));
```

This object contains messageText property and a lot of other properties.
Now I have task change searching by messageText and searching by other properties.
Search by message text:

```
q => q.QueryString(qs => qs.DefaultField(o => o.PropertyTextPart).Query(mainSearch).DefaultOperator(Operator.And));
```

And to search on another properties I need filter descriptor. But if I will add all other properties (it more than 30), it will curve code (because if somebody changes a property list he must change this code to). How can I exclude one field in search like:

```
q => q.QueryString(qfqqs => qfqqs.Query(mainSearch).DefaultOperator(Operator.And));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you map your model, you can exclude your `Field` with the property:

```
[Number(IncludeInAll = false)]
```

Then, when you make a `DefaultField("_all").Query(query)` search, the `Field` will be ignored, but when you find the element, the query-ignored field will be recover in the model.

Nowadays, I am looking for the way to make that property dynamic into a query.

I hope it will work for you!